# Android Studio - ¿Cómo achicar el tamaño de una vista programáticamente?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Tengo un **Text View** igual al de la imágen (1). Lo que quiero lograr es que al hacer **click** en el text view, este se achique quedando al igual que la imágen (2).

**Intenté con estas dos opciones las cuales solamente logran entorpecer mi text view** *(Lo agrandan muchisimo en altura y lo cambian de posición a otras coordenadas)*:

```
//OPCION 1
txt_fecha.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(20, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//OPCION 2
txt_fecha.setWidth(20);
```

**¿Qué puedo hacer para obtener el mismo resultado que muestro en el gráfico?**

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

**Edit:**

**Así se ve mi text view:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Así se ve mi text view al usar el código que adjunté arriba:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Define `LayoutParams` con el ancho deseado y configuralo a tu `TextView`:

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) txt_fecha.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 20;

txt_fecha.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por contestar. Al pegar este código en mi IDE, Android Studio me obliga a completar el código de la siguiente forma: ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) txt_fecha.getLayoutParams(); en donde "ConstraintLayout" puede ser una cantidad muy grande de vistas. Cual debo elegir y por que?

Comment: Usas un ConstraintLayout como contenedor del TextView ? si es así debes usar: (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)  @TomasM

Comment: Si. Uso Constraint Layout. Hice lo que me dijiste y me sigue pasando exactamente lo mismo que antes. Edité mi respuesta adjuntando imágenes de como se ve mi text view!